# How to store TimeofDay in shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, timepicker

I'm trying to store time picked from showTimePicker in shared preferences permanently, but am unable to do it

here is my code

```
 void saveData(String key, String value) async {
   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   await prefs.setString(key, value);
 }


 Future tweetTimePicker(BuildContext context) async {
   TimeOfDay initialTime = const TimeOfDay(hour: 9, minute: 0);
   final showDate = await showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: initialTime);

   if(showDate != null){
     setState(() {
       saveData('primaryTweetTime', showDate.toString());
       tweet_time = showDate;
     });
   }
 }

 void getTime() async {
   final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   final value = prefs.getString('primaryTweetTime');
   DateTime tweetTiming = DateTime.parse(value!);
   TimeOfDay tweetTime = TimeOfDay(hour: tweetTiming.hour, minute: tweetTiming.minute);

   TimeOfDay tweetTime = TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(tweetTiming); // tried this too but didn't worked
   setState(() {
     tweet_time = tweetTime; // still shows initial time
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to String before store it to Shared Preferences.

Step 1, declare and initialize date time variables

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
```

Step 2, initialize shared pref instance

```
final sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Step 3, store it to sharedPref

```
await sharedPrefs.setString('currentTime', now.toString());
```

Step 4, you can retrieve it like this

```
String currentTimeData = await sharedPrefs.getString('currentTime');
```

And dont forget, it's still a String. To use it as a DateTime, you should convert it back to DateTime like this

```
DateTime data = DateTime.parse(currentTimeData);
```

Thats all, hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as folllows: when saving

```
saveData("primaryTweetTime", showDate.hour.toString() + ":" + showDate.minute.toString());
```

when retrieving

```
TimeOfDay tweetTime = TimeOfDay(hour: value.split(":")[0], minute: value.split(":")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is just to store it as a String:

```
final now = DateTime.now();
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setString('primaryTweetTime', now.toString());
```

To get it back:

```
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
final value = prefs.getString('primaryTweetTime');
final dateTime = DateTime.parse(value!);
```